# foreach query PHP OOP Doctrine Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, foreach, doctrine

I have 3 tables, one contains document list (id, document, url), one contains onboarding status (user_id, document_id, status) and one contains user list (id, name).

In my controller, I have declared the variables calling each one of the repositories created with Doctrine.

```
$this->data['document_collection'] = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Documents')->findAll();
$current_user = $this->session->user_id;
$this->data['onboarding_data'] = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Onboarding')->findAll();
```

Then on my views page, I want to show a loop where the documents name and url list from the document list table which I did just fine like this:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
        foreach($document_collection as $onboarding):
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $onboarding->getDocument();
            ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <?php
            echo anchor($onboarding->getUrl(), "Download");
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

I want to add another  including checkboxes in my loop that will show checked if my $current_user matches the user_id of the onboarding status table for the corresponding document that is showing.

Example:

[image]

Comment: you are missing a closing endforeach; before </tbody>

Comment: @Vickel It's in my code already I skipped it to show where I'm having the issue

Comment: Is there a reason why you cant join the query?

Comment: @GabrielDube you should include the `endforeach` anyway to avoid confusion. Your sample code should be complete and reproducible with the least amount of effort to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Tiffany I just updated

Comment: @Ghostff I’m not sure how to do it when I have the entities with Doctrine

Comment: I never use doctrine. But it should be something like this https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#fetching-related-objects